# Android FragmentManager beginTransaction.add added fragment to hidden container

Tags: android, transactions, fragment

There is a MainFragment which contains LinearLayout with `id = main_container_layout`

1.Add **fragmentWithTypeA** to MainFragment->LinearLayout

```
beginTransaction.add(R.id.main_container_layout, fragmentWithTypeA, "555").commit())
```

**fragmentWithTypeA** contains LinearLayout with `id = container_layout`

2.Some action, add someFragment to main layout

```
transaction.hide(fragmentWithTypeA)
    .add(R.id.main_container_layout, someFragment, tag)
    .commit()
```

3.Some action in someFragment

4.Create **anotherFragmentWithTypeA**

```
transaction.hide(someFragment)
    .add(R.id.main_container_layout, anotherFragmentWithTypeA, tag)
    .commit()
```

5.inside **anotherFragmentWithTypeA** I try to add some content to LinearLayout

```
beginTransaction.add(R.id.container_layout, newFragment, "555").commit())
```

**Expected result:** newFragment should be added to **anotherFragmentWithTypeA**->LinearLayout

**actual result**: newFragment is added to **fragmentWithTypeA**->LinearLayout witch was hided in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

The one workaround is to set custom ID to **anotherFragmentWithTypeA**->LinearLayout after it was created in step 4. And than in step 5 use this custom ID as container id

```
class FragmentWithTypeA(customContainerId:Int = R.id.container_layout) extends Fragment {
private var _containerLayout : LinearLayout = null

override def onCreateView(inflater:LayoutInflater, container:ViewGroup, savedInstanceState:Bundle ) : View = {
    val view = getActivity.getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_id, null)

    _containerLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.container_layout).asInstanceOf[LinearLayout]
    _containerLayout.setId(customContainerId)

    view
}
```

}

......

```
val customContainerId = 7894
val anotherFragmentWithTypeA = new FragmentWithTypeA(customContainerId)

 transaction.hide(someFragment)
.add(R.id.main_container_layout, anotherFragmentWithTypeA, tag)
.commit()
```

.....

```
getFragmentManager.beginTransaction.add(customContainerId, newFragment, "111").commit
```